# Atomic write with Vim

Tags: vim

Can I configure Vim so it does an atomic write?

The default Vim behavior is:

- move `file.txt` to `file.txt~`
- write buffer contents to `file.txt`

But this causes some problem with `compass watch` for example

I would like behavior like:

- write buffer contents to `file.txt~`
- move `file.txt~` to `file.txt`

I've looked at the [backup](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backup%27), [backupcopy](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupcopy%27) and [writebackup](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27writebackup%27) options but I can't get Vim configured as I want.

Comment: I don't think that's doable but I'm curious as well. You should probably send the Compass people a bug report because `brunch`, `mocha` and other similar systems work well with Vim.

Answer (score 2):

`:set backupcopy=yes` is probably what you want.

You could also use the `backupskip' option on the paths you are particularly worried about.

Comment: I don't think `backupcopy=yes` does what OP wants. It appears to.copy the existing file to a backup file first, then overwrite the existing file in place. It's like the OP's first example except with an initial copy instead of a move. That said, it may still solve the particular issue OP had.

Comment: the thing that sucks about this though is that backup files will start polluting your working directories

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how atomic writes are typically handled in arbitrary software. I could be wrong, but something like this is probably handled or configurable at the kernel level (and that would seem like the optimal place to handle such a notion as atomic writes for multiple reasons such as: efficiency, direct access to hardware, the DRY principle, application agnosticism, etc.). A more manual and user-space way that I can think of accomplishing this however would be to first write to some new/unique/random file inside of `/tmp`, then `mv` that file that you just wrote under `/tmp` into place. You can use Vim's `tempname()` function to help you accomplish this in a platform-agnostic manner (see `:help tempname()`).